# How to add a variable into object's name in C#?

Tags: c#

Let's say I want a function like this:

```
private void ShowLabel(byte Variable)
{
labelXXX.Show();
}
```

But with **Variable**'s value instead of **XXX**. Is it possible?

Comment: You can do this with Reflection, but it's non-trivial.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: WPF? Win Forms? ASP.NET?

Comment: Another programmer coming from PHP would be my guess ;-)

Comment: @Jim, reflection is not needed, and this IS trivial. (in at least WinForms, WPF, and ASP.NET)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need reflection, you can use

- Windows Forms: [`Controls.Find("label" + Variable.ToString())`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx)
- ASP.NET: [`FindControl("label" + Variable.ToString())`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)
- WPF: [`FindName("label" + Variable.ToString())`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx)

But using a `Dictionary<byte, Label>`, [as suggested by CodeInChaos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111030/how-to-add-a-variable-into-objects-name-in-c/4111055#4111055), would be preferable.

Comment: I stand corrected.  My non-GUI focus is showing.  Nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

you could create an array of the Labels and use the value of Variable as the index to that array.  But you question is pretty vague.  Could you give more info on why you need to do this?

Comment: Actually I don't really need this. :P I'm just curious if this is possible as I couldn't find anything about it. I'm not interested in other soulutions for making a function that I wrote as example, only if it is possible to simply combine a variable and object's name, but I guess it's not unfortunately. :)

Answer (score 1):

While you can do it with reflection, it smells. If you have many labels which are only distinguished by a number, perhaps create them at runtime and put them in List or dictionary, so you can look them up from the ID.

You could iterate over all the children of the parent control, compare their name to the name you want to find the control you want. But that has a bad smell.